# How does Collection.sort(List<T>,Comparator<T>) work with the order of input?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

For example, if I want to sort people with ID, and I write an inner class that implements comparator like

```
public class IDCompare implements Comparator<People>{

    // this order of compare will sort in ascending order
    @Override
    public int compare(People o1, People o2) {
        return o1.getID() - o2.getID();
    }
    // this order of compare will sort in descending order
    @Override
    public int compare(People o1, People o2) {
        return o2.getID() - o1.getID();
    }
}
```

How did `Collection.sort()` method know the order of sort and implement my according to the input order?

Comment: Did you try compiling that code?

Comment: like you said, the order is determined by the comparison function

Comment: (Additionally, you really shouldn't use that approach to implement a comparison. It will cause problems with extreme values.)

Comment: also, when not giving a comparator, you can only sort comparables, which define their order themselves

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the Comparator interface documentation, the [`compare(T o1, To2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)) method must return:

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Which is exactly what your code is doing:

- When `o1.getID()` is lower than `o2.getID()`, the subtraction returns a negative number.
- When `o1.getID()` is equal to `o2.getID()`, the subtraction returns zero.
- When `o1.getID()` is greater than `o2.getID()`, the subtraction returns a positive number.

The resulting "sign" is in return used to sort the collection.

Beware that as Jon Skeet stated in the comments extreme values may cause problems due to overflow.